# Updating R to 3.2 from 3.02

Tags: linux, r, linux-mint

I am on Linux Mint. I have 3.0.2 version of R installed. I need to use library which was just released and requires R version of 3.2. http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/html/CODEX.html

What would I do to update my R version to 3.2?

I've tried to add some repositories to apt, but then not only it tries to install R 3.1.2, but installation itself does not work.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.1.2-1precise0) but 3.0.2-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.1.2-1precise0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I've tried to compile 3.2 from source, but running configure gives the following error:

```
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
```

Can anyone advice?

Comment: Where did you get the R-3.2.0 source, as it will appear starting March 19?

Comment: It is available as a prerelease version here: http://www.r-project.org/ It is the first link in the news section.

Comment: This is the beta version of R-3.1.3.

Comment: Oh darn. You are right.

Comment: So I've ran sudo apt-get buil-dep r-base-core to get all dependecies. And after that I was able to compile R from source. I downloaded it from the link above. But when I launch compiled version of R it says "R version 3.1.2 Patched (2015-02-25 r67891) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"

Answer (score 1):

I found good instructions on how to update R here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/218708/installing-latest-version-of-r-base

In my case running:

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base-core
```

Before installing new version of R helped. However, this only allows me to install R 3.1.2, which does not solve my problem completely.